# Set active printer in PrintOut OLE function

Tags: c++, excel, com, ms-office, ole

I use PrintOut function

```
Excel::_ApplicationPtr app("Excel.Application");

app->Visible[0] = false;

Excel::_WorkbookPtr book = app->Workbooks->Add();
Excel::_WorksheetPtr sheet = book->Worksheets->Item[1];
....

book->Worksheets->PrintOut(1, 1, 1, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, false);
```

But it's wrong. The defeniton of this function is:

```
PrintOut ( const _variant_t & From, const _variant_t & To, const _variant_t & Copies, const _variant_t & Preview, const _variant_t & ActivePrinter, const _variant_t & PrintToFile, const _variant_t & Collate, const _variant_t & PrToFileName, const _variant_t & IgnorePrintAreas, long lcid );
```

How I can right set ActivePrinter ?

Comment: What goes wrong?  What do you expect or need to happen?

Comment: I don't know How to get ActivePrinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840355.aspx) *Active Printer* is in fact the name of the printer you want to use, so it is a string and it is also an optional parameter, so I guess you can just pass empty variant there:

```
book->Worksheets->PrintOut( .., _variant_t(), ... );
```

Comment: I try right to pass right parameter: pChartXYZ->PrintOut(1, 1, 1, true, app->ActivePrinter, NULL, NULL, false, false); but chart isn't printing.

Comment: There is printing dialog and quickly hide it. But dont't adding to printing queue this task